# error using compare code

Tags: php

If i've database `my_table (id,word)` as following

[image: my_table (id,word)]

and i've some posted text called `$name` then i want to know if `$name` have any word like words i've stored in my database `my_table (id,word)`

so i'm using this code

```
$name = "Hello lovely world"; // no bad words

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$commentArray = explode(" ", $name);
$counter      = count($commentArray);
$check        = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    for ($i == 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

        if (strcasecmp($commentArray[$i], $row['word'])) {
            $check = 1;
        }

    }

}

if ($check == 1) {
    echo "banned";
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "passed";
}
```

however it always results in `echo "banned";` even if i `$name` is clear of any bad words i've stored in `my_table` so there might be something wrong here !

anyhelp

Comment: Thanks all , it now works perfect and i've added to my mind 1) strcasecmp returns 0 when it matches 2) Extra care about syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcasecmp` returns 0 when it matches ([PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)), so you should edit your code:

```
if (strcasecmp($commentArray[$i], $row['word']) == 0)
```

Furthermore, you have a syntax error in your for loop. It should be `for ($i = 0; ...`

Comment: ~ thanks , it works perfect , never knew about strcasecmp returns 0 when it matches before , i'll review php manual.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.

```
for ($i = 0...
```

And not

```
for ($i == 0...
```

Also, you should indent your code properly, it looks better and it'll help you later on.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) returns 0 if the strings are equal. You ought to change it to `if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, I'd suggest storing only lowercased words in the table, lowercasing the input text first, and then replacing the whole strcasecmp loop with an [`in_array`](http://us.php.net/in_array)`($row['word'], $commentArray);`. And `break;` after the first match.

But this entire approach doesn't scale - you're selecting all the entries in the table. If your table grows beyond a certain size, that will be a serious bottleneck and you'll need to look into matching on the DB side.